# Kubernetes passing a unqiue ID to each pod in a job with parallelism > 1

Tags: kubernetes

Reading the [Kubernetes official docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#job-patterns) on Job parallel execution (e.g. one job, multiple pods with `parallelism` set to > 1), under the section, "[Parallel execution for Jobs / Parallel Jobs with a fixed completion count](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs)," the documentation states:

> **not implemented yet:** Each Pod is passed a different index in the range 1 to .spec.completions.

This statement suggests that a future version of Kubernetes will be able to pass a unique counter to each pod in a job with `parallelism` > 1.

Since this is in the official documentation as of (17 Mar 2021) I would like to know if there is an official timeline or expected release version for this feature. It would alleviate a lot of pain for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this feature will be released as alpha in 1.21 which is due in a few weeks. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/98812 has details and links to the KEP.